# Usage of Simple Present between speakers

Tags: conversational-deletion

Is the use of "Do" in the begining of interrogative sentence necessary? I means, casual conversation.

> Does he play tennis?
>
> He plays tennis?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's a huge mistake. It was supposed to be `Simple Present`

Comment: I've retracted my close vote, since your revision raises additional issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*He plays tennis?* does not involve merely deleting the supporting *do* at the head of the sentence—that would yield

> *He play tennis?*

without the 3d-person singular present inflection *-s* on *play*. That would be an example of [conversational-deletion](/questions/tagged/conversational-deletion). This is comparatively rare with 3d-person questions like this, but it might arise in contexts like these:

> **A:** I can't find anybody to partner with for the tournament.
> **B:** Hmm. What about Brian? He play tennis?
>
> **A:** This new guy's quite an athlete: played football at Tech.
> **B:** He play tennis?

Your sentence is something quite different, an echoic question. This has the syntactic structure of an ordinary declarative *He play**s** tennis*, spoken with a rising intonation at the end—that's what the *?* signifies. Such questions demand confirmation of what has just been spoken:

> **A:** I see Brian's entered the company tennis tournament.
> **B:** He plays tennis? I thought he had a bum knee.

Comment: I was writing an answer myself, but I deleted it because yours was better!  As an aside, some dialects of English, like AAVE, do regularly use formations like "He play tennis?"  But that's a little bit beyond most neophyte English speakers, and for SAE, you're absolutely correct.